# p5.js: Random colors and save as pdf function

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script>
var angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 400);
  background(255, 0, 0);
  noStroke();
  fill(0, 102);
}

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed === true) {
    angle += 5;
    var val = cos(radians(angle)) * 20.0;
    for (var a = 0; a < 360; a += 75) {
      var xoff = cos(radians(a)) * val;
      var yoff = sin(radians(a)) * val;
      fill(random(0, 255));
      ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, random(20, 120), random(20, 120));
    }
  }
}
</script>

<button>Save as PDF</button>
```

I need:

A) The colors of the objects are currently grey (from white to black). I need three different reds in a random sequence. How is it possible to code this?

B) The "Save as PDF" button should work ...

Comment: Hi Anna, your question indicates to me you haven't finished your tutorial in p5.js, you should really try to do this. The save to PDF question makes me feel like you are trying to let others do your work (it's possible but a ton of work). Maybe somebody here will be kind enough to help you with your questions. But if not, this is why.

Comment: Hello @ikwillem, the function to save a PDF is in general easy, I think. But I don't know how to get this on a HTML button ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part A you could do this

```
fill(random(0, 255),random(0, 255),random(0, 255))
```

But I'd suggest you take another look at [P5.js](https://p5js.org/) documentation to understand why and how this works

And for B:
You can try using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<button id="download">download</button>
<script>
  var download = document.getElementById('download');
  download.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: And how is it possible to combine P5 and jsPDF?

Comment: Seeing this question... Please read up on how does script tag works. You import jsPDF with the first line in my second code snippet